laravel issue with sending data to rabbitmq
i have this issue in my code: i have 2 microservices laravel 10: in the 1st one i send to the queue a variable like this:
        Queue::connection('rabbitmq')->push('App\Jobs\UpdateProductStock', $orderData);

and in the job that will recieve this it shows :
local.ERROR: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $orderData ]] in class App\Jobs\UpdateProductStock {"exception":"[object]
in the reciever job i have :
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;
use VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Connectors\RabbitMQConnector;

class UpdateProductStock implements ShouldQueue
{


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public $orderData;

    public function __construct($orderData)
    {
        $this->orderData = $orderData;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info("Test job executed successfully.");

so i understand that the variable sent by the 1st service was not recieved to the 2nd one.
any help please ?
i have tried to change the job structure like this:
use VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Connectors\RabbitMQConnector as BaseJob;

class UpdateProductStock extends BaseJob
{


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     * @return void
     */


    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function fire()
    {$payload = $this->getRawBody();

but it gives indefined method getRawBody

try:
Queue::connection('rabbitmq')->push(new App\Jobs\UpdateProductStock($orderData));


i can't i push into the queue from a microservice to a second microservice, so if i will push like this:
Queue::connection('rabbitmq')->push(new App\Jobs\UpdateProductStock($orderData));
in the first microservice, i will be asked to import the class of that job,  so that job is in another microservice

Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
